# What is the meaning of ～しにたちよったんじゃ?

Tags: words, phrases

Here is the sentence containing the phrase.

ちと 忠告【ちゅうこく】**しにたちよったんじゃ**。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's ちょっと忠告しに、立ち寄ったんだ。 （I just dropped by to give you a piece of advice. ） in a regional dialect or the role language for old speakers.

~~しに means するために, "(in order) to~~".